# auto incrementation in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a following table Asset(assetID, assetType) where assetID is the primary key of the table.

In oracle Apex, I want the users to be able to create a new instance of asset. But so far, it seems that I cannot do auto-increment for assetID instead of letting users type it manually every time.

For example, currently if you want to create an asset, I need user's input of assetID and assetType and if there is an assetID that already exists, it does not create a same instance but tells the user that assetID already exists.

I want to change this to auto-increment so the assetID is not all over the place. How do I do this?

Comment: use a sequence, or max(assetId) + 1

Comment: which component are you using? tabular form? form on a report? ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence and trigger on Asset table

First create a Sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Asset_AssetID_SEQ 
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;
```

Then create trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BI_Asset_AssetID   
  before insert ON Asset               
  for each row
begin   
  if :NEW.AssetID is null then 
    select Asset_AssetID_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.AssetID from dual; 
  end if; 
end;
```

On user side, insert only assetType info:

```
Insert into Asset (assetType) values ('Cars');
```

you will have the assetId auto assigned.